# Unable to draw border on Image view

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to set border on imagview , once i set image on imageview border gets disappeared. Image is overlayed on the whole view. Trying to get image from gallery.

**image.xml**

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="157dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
   />
```

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" >
</padding>
```

Any Help would be Appreciated.

Thanks in  Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the padding to `ImageView` few `dp` and see if you can see the border. Actually remove the padding from `Shape` and set the padding to `ImageView`.

Comment: Don't get you. But you can't copy the images directly to apk. But you can copy the image to a private folder for the apk.

Comment: Please read this doc [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: I know about data storage. Thanks for the help. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the image view inside a layout and make the backgroung of that wrapper layout to the boarder.